# Terminal Output Vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm learning how to write a simple "Hello World" program in Java. I want to change the terminal output so that only the output is shown. I don't want to see the extra text.. [Here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY56q.png)

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add `"console": "internalConsole"` in your **launch.json** like :

```
"configurations": [
           {
             "type": "java",
             "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - App",
             "request": "launch",
             "mainClass": "com.test.maven.App",
             "console": "internalConsole",
             "projectName": "my.app"
           }
         ]
```

then it will show in `Debug Console`